# R function to determine the overlap between two date intervals -- DescTools Interval Function

Tags: r, intervals, lubridate, desctools

I'm looking for a way to determine the overlap (in days) between two date intervals.  I have columns startdate1, enddate1, startdate2, enddate2.  I want an additional column with the number of days of overlap between the intervals (startdate1, enddate1) and (startdate2, enddate2).
For example, I want to end up with something like this:

```
startdate1      enddate1      startdate2      enddate2      overlap
1/1/2020        1/10/2020     1/6/2020        1/16/2020     5
1/15/2020       1/29/2020     1/6/2020        1/20/2020     6
1/15/2020       1/29/2020     1/17/2020       1/20/2020     4
```

I've been trying to achieve this with the Interval function from the DescTools package:

```
df1$overlap<- Interval(as.Date(c(df1$startdate1, df1$enddate1)), as.Date(c(df1$startdate2, df1$enddate2)))
```

But I get the error Error:

> as.Date.numeric(c(df1$startdate1, df1$enddate1)) : 'origin' must be supplied"

I have also looked into the lubridate package-- I used the interval function (different from the DescTools Interval above) to create columns interval1 and interval2, but I'm not aware of a function that can calculate the days of overlap between them.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can achieve this by simply subtracting `enddate1` from `startdate2`. You can do this with base `R` functions like `as.Date()`:

```
as.Date(enddate1, "%m/%d/%Y") - as.Date(startdate2, "%m/%d/%Y") + 1
```

The string `%m/%d/%Y` specifies the format of your dates, in your case month/day/year. I add the `+1` because the above calculates the difference between dates (like `10 - 6 = 4`), not including the start date, while to get the overlap we want to also count the start day itself.

Comment: The reason I didn't do this is because the overlap can occur in either direction.  For example, interval1=(1/15/20, 1/29/20), interval2=(1/6/20, 1/20/20).  In that case I would need enddate2-startdate1 instead of enddate1-startdate2.  I also have intervals that fully overlap-- interval1=(1/15/20-1/29/20), interval2=(1/17/20-1/22/20) -- interval2 is fully contained in interval1, so in that case I just need the length of interval2.  I want to take care of all these scenarios in one calculation.

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect this -- thanks for pointing it out.